# Can't set Account on Case from Trigger

Tags: trigger, case, account

I need to be able to set the account on a case when the case is created. I have the following trigger. The debug statements show as expected, but the account is not getting updated on the case. What am I doing wrong?

```
trigger SetAccount on Case (before insert, before update) {
    Account acc = [select id from account where account.name='ABC'];
     for (Case caseObj:Trigger.new) {
        system.debug('caseObj.account before: '+caseObj.account);
        if(caseObj.account == null){
            caseObj.account = acc;
            system.debug('caseObj.account after: '+caseObj.account);
        }          
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try doing the following. Notice I am using Case.AccountId instead of Case.Account. Also, need to make sure that the initial query is returning something, or else you will get an error further along.

```
trigger SetAccount on Case (before insert, before update) {
    Account acc = [select id from account where account.name='ABC'];
    if(acc != null)
    {
     for (Case caseObj:Trigger.new) {
        system.debug('caseObj.account before: '+caseObj.accountId);
        if(caseObj.accountId == null){
            caseObj.accountId = acc.Id;
            system.debug('caseObj.account after: '+caseObj.accountId);
        }          
     }
    }
}
```